# Какую библиотеку выбрать для рисования графиков в android и ios?

Tags: android, ios

Встала задача рисования графиков максимальной похожести. Есть ли какая-нибудь либа, которая сделает максимально похожие графики для ios и android. Какие есть решения?

Comment: Так уж вышло, что для Android и iOS разработка ведется на разных языках, и библиотекидля них тоже на разных языках. Так что придется вам искать две отдельных библиотеки. Можете конечно попробовать сделать кроссплатформенное приложение, на чем-то вроде Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть две бибилиотеки под обе платформы с визуально похожими отображениями https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart для Android и https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts для iOS

Comment: Спасибо! На MPAndroidChart уже наткнулся. Надеюсь, быстро разберусь.